# AAPT Build Error Android Resource Fail :Style

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, aapt, aapt2

Im trying to build my Android Studio project with Gradle. However I keep receiving the following error.

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
>     C:\Users\rhnow.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\ac23c912e546e4fe8c1c7df0b070c599\res\values\values.xml:1454:5-1461:13: AAPT: error: :style>.

C:\Users\rhnow.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\ac23c912e546e4fe8c1c7df0b070c599\res\values\values.xml:1454:5-1461:13: AAPT: error: :style>.

Ive tried to clean and rebuild along with downgrading gradle and SDK Versions.

Line 1454 - 1461

```
<style name="Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:layout">@layout/abc_alert_dialog_material</item>
        <item name="android:listLayout">@layout/abc_select_dialog_material</item>
        <item name="android:listItemLayout">@layout/select_dialog_item_material</item>
        <item name="android:multiChoiceItemLayout">@layout/select_dialog_multichoice_material</item>
        <item name="android:singleChoiceItemLayout">@layout/select_dialog_singlechoice_material</item>
        <item name="android:buttonIconDimen">@dimen/abc_alert_dialog_button_dimen</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an internet connection. The dependency/s might be downloaded incompleted.
Make sure using latest Gradle plugins, if the plugins still throw and error, try to downgrade back to one-version-lower-than-latest. Is that AAPT v1? Use AAPT2 for Gradle plugin 3.0.0 and higher, refers here;

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2

Clean, Rebuild, and Make Project.

If nothing changed, try to Invalidate Cache, that also give you optional selection with and without restart the Android Studio.
Hope this helps.